# Can't run grunt serve after yeoman install osx 10.6.8

Tags: sass, gruntjs, yeoman

This is my first foray into this type of web dev.

I've tried installing a site via yeoman to have the grunt serve active while I learn SASS. Every time I try doing this I seem to get different errors that I don't understand.

Setup:

- Mac OSX 10.6.8
- Sass 3.4.18 (Selective Steve)
- XAMPP 5.6.3-0
- ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin10.0]
- Compass 1.0.3 (Polaris)
- npm 2.14.3
- node v4.1.0
- bower 1.5.3
- git version 2.5.3   <-- EDIT: forgot about that, took ages to install too!

I've made a /test folder on the desktop and then follow this guide https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp. I had followed other guides prior to this, the most useful was this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gKiaLSJW5xI

I get the usual options I'm told to expect, but it say 'SASS' not 'SASS and Compass', why is this? I have both installed.

If I install all 3, the grunt command hangs on all different parts (grunt serve won't work as a result). The grunt serve error is:

> Warning: OptionParser::InvalidOption: invalid option: --source-map
>         Use --trace for backtrace. Use --force to continue.

I'm going to try building with each different combination of yo webapp builds and edit this comment with some of the errors.

EDIT 1: Reinstalling now, bootstrap and sass (no modernizer). I'm getting loads of node-sass errors. No idea why.

EDIT 2: I followed this guide again before another install, (I can't post the link as my rep is less than 10, its from yeoman.io /setup) I still get yo webapp install errors like this:

> optipng pre-build test failed
>   ℹ compiling from source
>   ✔ optipng built successfully
>
> npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bufferutil@1.2.1

There are also LOADS of errors under something called 'CCX(target)'

> gyp ERR! build error
>
> gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)

etc. it goes on for a while. Also:

> npm ERR! node-sass@3.3.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
>
> npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
>
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>
> npm ERR!     node scripts/build.js
>
> npm ERR! You can get their info via:
>
> npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-sass
>
> npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

EDIT 3: I tried just install bootstrap (without SASS or Modernizer) and noticed this error-

> CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
>
> cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=gnu++0x"
>
> make: *** [Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o] Error 1

...after searching it seems to be an error associated with GCC. I have GCC 4.2.1 (which I'm assured is ancient history) but I'm currently downloading the 'kennethreitz' installer for Snow Leopard off github.

EDIT 4: I just tapped in 'brew install gcc', hope it updates... time to play the waiting game.

In the meantime, any other tips on getting a similar setup on 10.6.8 (ie. auto-reload, sass, bootstrap)?

EDIT 5: Wow, that took a *really* long time, still on GCC 4.2.1 and everything is the same, ie. doesn't work. Should I give up? What are my alternatives for a web dev workflow?

Comment: I have a hunch that maybe the OS is contributing to the problem. OSX 10.6 was superseded in 2011 and has been mostly discontinued, so it's possible that some of your build tools just don't support it any more.